# Proving certificate of inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I have a question about proving the certificate of inequality in the given question:

If there exists $y$ such that $y^T A \leq 0$ and $y^T b < 0$, then $Ax = b$, $x \leq$ 0 has no solution.

I believe that this is true because if $y^Tb < 0$ and $y^T A \leq 0$, then there can not be a vector $x$ that satisfy $Ax=b$ without $x$ being positive. Would anyone be able to verify this or to prove in a formal way?

Comment: You may look up [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) in any undergraduate level textbook on optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $z$ is a vector such that $z\leq 0$. Therefore for $x\leq 0$ we get:
$$
z^T.x=z_1x_1+...+z_nx_n \geq 0
$$
Now if $Ax=b,x\leq 0$ has a solution then we can see that there is a vector $z\leq 0$, such that $z^T.x<0$ which is against the above conclusion.

To see this, multiply two sides of the equation by $y^T$, and choose $z=y^TA$. Then we get:
$$
Ax=b\implies y^TAx=y^Tb\implies z^T.x < 0 
$$